# расширение для postgresql

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, сборка

Надо написать расширение для postgresql на Ubuntu, которое обеспечит прозрачное шифрование данных (TDE). Возникла идея добавить свои модули в исходники и/или похимичить с ними в отдельности, а потом всё собрать. Действовал по инструкции для просто сборки из исходников https://eax.me/postgresql-build/. Среди флагов скрипта configure `./configure --help` обнаружил следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] и [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос: это те флаги, которыми стоит воспользоваться, и, если да, в каком виде должны быть файлы расширения и где они должны лежать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала вам необходимо выяснить, можете ли вы реализовать задуманное силами расширения вообще либо вам необходимо менять основной код базы несовместимым способом - и это тогда уже будет патч, но не extension.

Для этого собственно выяснить, что именно вам нужно менять в поведении базы, предоставляет ли база необходимую гибкость в этих местах. В PostgreSQL расширение может сделать довольно многое, но не всё.

### Если возможностей extension достаточно

Вы не трогаете исходный код postgresql, как и вовсе не обязаны собирать базу из исходников. Вам понадобятся заголовочные файлы и утилита `pg_config` из комплекта поставки базы.

В любом месте где угодно [вы описываете](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-pgxs.html) свой `Makefile` с вызовом `pg_config`. Последний обеспечит для вас все необходимые пути. Затем пишете код, прочую обвязку расширения (посмотрите для примеров на `contrib/` из дерева исходного кода базы), затем простым `make` и `make install` ваше расширение устанавливаются в подходящее место и становится доступно для использования базой в `create extension` и релевантных настройках.

### Если расширения недостаточно

То вы работаете напрямую в дереве исходного кода postgresql, изменяя непосредственно код базы. Далее собираете как будто ничего в коде не меняли, обычным `./configure` и далее по списку.

---

Касательно реализации - смотря что именно вы хотите сделать. [Начните отсюда](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/031401d3f41d%245c70ed90%241552c8b0%24%40lab.ntt.co.jp), это наиболее свежая дискуссия о реализации TDE в postgresql. Скорей всего возможностей расширения будет недостаточно.

Comment: огромное спасибо, хорошее начало, будем думать